# NServiceBus - Difference between DefineEndpointName and app.config MessageEndpointMappings

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

Would somebody be able to explain what the difference is between configuring the EndpointName in Configure.DefineEndpointName and specifying it in the app.config under MessageEndpointMappings?

i.e.

```
.DefineEndpointName("Something.MessageQueue")
```

And

```
 <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Something.Messages" Endpoint="Something.MessageQueue" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the name of the *current* endpoint to "Something.MessageQueue":

```
.DefineEndpointName("Something.MessageQueue")
```

This tells the configured endpoint that when sending messages that reside in assembly Something.Messages, the *destination* endpoint to send them to is "SomethingServer.MessageQueue".  I changed the endpoint name in your example to illustrate that they are different endpoints.

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Something.Messages" Endpoint="SomethingServer.MessageQueue" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

I should note that the endpoint names *could* be the same endpoints if you want to send a message to yourself (which can be useful from time to time).

**Edit**

Documentation links:

- http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/how-to-specify-your-input-queue-name (the syntax you are using is v4).
- http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/how-do-i-specify-to-which-destination-a-message-will-be-sent

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know where this is explained in the documentation as I struggled to find anything concrete and concise?